# Executing two sql queries in a single Command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I know the latter query would replace the former. But can I execute the both?
Or is it mandatory to create two commands.

```
MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
MyCommand.CommandText = "Insert into ();
MyCommand.CommandText = "Insert into (); 
MyConnection.Open();
MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MyConnection.Close();
```

Comment: You can issue multiple commands in a semicolumn separated batch. `MyCommand.CommandText = "Insert into ();Insert into ();"`

Comment: Alternatively, change the fourth line's operator to '+='.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - You should post an answer.

Comment: @MikeChristensen ok will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine multiple queries into a batch and send it as one command to the server. So you can do either

```
MyCommand.CommandText = "Insert into (); Insert into ();"
```

or

```
MyCommand.CommandText = "Insert into ();"
MyCommand.CommandText += "Insert into ();"
```

Note that this is not recommended if you have many queries or any kind of flow control logic, in this case offload the execution to server-side stored procedure.